# How to create a directory with intermediate directories using Titanium SDK?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, create-directory

How can I create a directory with intermediate directories using Titanium SDK 5.3.0?

The documentation http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem.File says

`createDirectory( ) : Boolean`

doesn't have any parameters contrary to

`deleteDirectory( [recursive] ) : Boolean`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn, http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem.File-method-createDirectory is out-dated resp. wrong...

Looking into Titanium (iOS) source file `TiFilesystemFileProxy.m` brings clarity:

The function `-(id)createDirectory:(id)args` also uses one boolean parameter like its counterpart `-(id)deleteDirectory:(id)args`, so you can  use for example

```
myDir.createDirectory(true);
```

in your JavaScript code to create `mydir` at path  `/subdir/subsubdir/mydir` with intermediate directories (`myDir` is here an `Ti.Filesystem.File` object).